# Complexity of computing $n^{n^2}$

Tags: complexity-theory, integers, number-theory

What is the complexity of computing $n^{n^2},\;n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: What have *you* tried? Which machine and cost model do you assume?

Answer (score 12):

By using the fast Fourier transform, multiplications on $k$-bit numbers can be done in time $\tilde{O}(k)$ (where the tilde [signifies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_O_notation#Extensions_to_the_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) that we're ignoring polylogarithmic factors). By repeated squaring, we can compute $n^{n^2}$ with $O(\log n)$ multiplications, and each multiplication involves no number larger than $n^{n^2}$, which has roughly $n^2 \log_2 n$ bits. So the total amount of time required is $\tilde{O}(n^2(\log n)^2)=\tilde{O}(n^2)$.

Answer (score 3):

**Edited in response to comments** 
The time to compute $f(n) = n^{n^2}$ can be decomposed into the time required to compute $f_1(n) = n^2$ and that required to perform $n ^ {f_1(n)}$. I'll assume that multiplying an $m$ bit number by an $n$ bit number takes exactly $mn$ time by the school book method ; additions, etc. are constant time. As a result, computing $n^2$ takes $\log_2^2 (n)$ time.

Suppose that we use binary exponentiation for computing $f(n)$.  Binary exponentiation does two kinds of operations in computing $f(n)$: squaring the current product, and multiplying the current product by $n$, according to whether the current bit in the binary expansion of $n^2$ is 0 or 1. In the worst case, $n^2$ is a power of two, so that binary exponentiation repeatedly squares its current product until  it reaches the answer.Note that $n^2$ has $m'=\lceil 2 \log_2(n) \rceil $ bits, so that the number of such squarings is $m= m'-1$. This is the case we analyze  further below.

The first squaring takes $t_1=\log_2^2(n)$ time, resulting in a $o_1=2 \log_2(n)$-bit product .  The second squaring takes in two $o_1$ bit 
numbers and runs in $t_2=o_1^2$ time, resulting in a $o_2=2o_1$-bit product. Continuing, the $i$-th step takes $t_i = 4^{i-1}\log^2_2 n$ time and outputs a $o_i=2^{i} \log_2 (n)$ -bit product. This process stops at the $m$-th step; as a result, it takes time

$T _{exp} =\sum _{[1..m]} t_i = \log_2 ^2 (n) \sum_{[1..m]} 4^i = \frac{4^m -1} {3} \log_2 ^2 n$.

When the initial squaring cost is included, we find we need time at most

${T_{exp} + \log_2^2{n}}$

*Note*

- I omitted some floors and ceilings in the computations, hoping they would not materially affect the answer.

  I deliberately omitted an $O$-based analysis in favour of an exact upper bound just to be rigorous.

  The above reasoning also makes clear why my earlier analysis was flawed. The $O$ notation was used in a fast-and-loose way, and it conveniently omitted constants so that, for instance, $\sum t_i $ magically became $O(\log n)$.

  The multiplications can be always speeded up by FFT and other methods.

Comment: How have you got $\mathcal{O}(1)$ complexity for computation of $n^{2}$?

Comment: I'm you're going to say that multiplication of two $n$-bit numbers takes $O(\log n)$ time instead of $O(1)$ time, you need to figure that into the cost of the binary exponentiation also.

Comment: Note that the final result has $n^2\log_2 n$ bits. It's very hard to compute $n^2\log_2 n$ bits in $O(\log n)$ time.

Comment: Fair point, I'll take note

Comment: Here's another way to get the same result. Computing $n^n$ with binary exponentiation requires $O(\log n)$ multiplications. Call that $a$. Then $n^{n^2} = (n^n)^n = a^n$. Computing $a^n$ from $a$ requires another $O(\log n)$ multiplications. So overall the computation takes $O(\log n)$ multiplications.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: That depends on the machine and cost model. It is not unusual to assume a RAM model with contant cost for additions.

Comment: @Raphael, true, but in this case given the size of the resulting answer it may be a bad assumption. Consider that even at n=7 a 128-bit word size is overrun. Though if one allows precision loss with floating point I'm not sure what is correct anymore.

Comment: @Raphael: It is not unusual to assume a RAM model with contant cost for additions **of $O(\log n)$-bit integers**.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: Floating point arithmetics are irrelevant here as $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I don't know that complexity theory deals with FP numbers at all.

Comment: There is absolutely no reasonable model in which this answer is correct. The only way to compute an $\omega(n^2)$-bit number with polylog many operations (be that word or bit operations) is by some kind of divine magic.

Comment: @Downvoter: can you explain?

Comment: There are no downvotes on this question. But I believe I removed my original upvote because I thought that the edit removed the aspects of the answer that led me to upvote originally, and moreover claims that the original analysis was flawed, while I thought the original analysis was fine under the assumption that multiplication takes constant time. Also $4^m \approx (2^m)^2 \approx (n^2)^2 = n^4$ while Micah has a $n^2$ bound.

Comment: Well, no - @Sasho & Thomas Andrews are right. I understand your concern about the $n^2$ bound but I am unable to find holes in my reasoning.

Comment: The $n^4$ is because you use the bound for gradeschool multiplication. Basically, the running time is dominated by the last multiplication, which is of two $B = n^2$-bit numbers. Even Karatsuba does better than $B^2$, and FFT is nearly linear time. The downvote was mine, which I removed after you edited the answer.